# Is this kind of tire damage from a landscaping brick?

Tags: tires, damage, parking, sidewall-damage

My wife and I use surplus landscaping bricks as bump-stops in our garage.  They are maybe 1.5" thick and 12" wide, and are used as stop indicators at a creeping pace only.  The tire is from a 2013 Veloster, with 13k miles, so it's still fairly new.  We will be replacing the tire, but I'm wondering if we should replace the bricks, or if this damage was likely from a pothole at speed instead.

[image: Tire bubble]

Comment: Is that a bubble in the sidewall?  If so, my advice still stands: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/2769/57

Comment: @BobCross: yes, it's a bubble in the sidewall.  We have an appointment at the dealer Monday, to see how much Hyundai's 100K warranty is worth.  Everybody who's seen it in person says it's from a manufacturing defect.

Comment: Hyundai's warranty does NOT cover consumables like tires. The tire manufacturer provides a tire warranty (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bricks as you describe will not cause this type of tire damage/issues. It seems to me you have a defective tire or you hit something while car was traveling at speed (I doubt this though, as you'd probably see damage to the wheel as well).

On a side note, using the bricks as bump stops in the garage is a pretty good idea, in my book.